# Background binding in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resources, converters

i got the following Problem.
I have a ListBox, which items are templated by a DataTemplate. This Template has a Grid, and i want the background of that grid to change corresponding to a value. The value is calculated by a converter, and the converter gets passed a CollectionView that is created within the Grids Resources (it needs to be created within the DataTemplate, because the data is dependant of the name chosen in the ListBox).

I just can't get that to work!
I tried so many different things, but i think the problem is that i want to access the Grid's Resources on a level where the Resource is not available (Grid.Background). On the other hand, when i move the CollectionView to the Resources of the DataTemplate, i can't seem to access that Resource (converter doesn't work anymore then)...  I hope i have made it understandable enough what i am aiming for^^.

Here is all the relevant Code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:newConverter x:Key="newConverter" />

    <Style x:Key="personButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="listBoxTemplate" >
        <Grid Name="personGrid" Margin="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items" Source="{Binding XPath=item}">
                    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="@name"/>
                    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                </CollectionViewSource>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="1" Content="&#x2713;" Style="{StaticResource personButton}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Click="button_person_balanced"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="1" Content="&#x00D7;" Style="{StaticResource personButton}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Click="button_person_delete"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}, Converter={StaticResource newConverter}, ConverterParameter=items}" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}, Converter={StaticResource newConverter}, ConverterParameter=date}" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}, Converter={StaticResource newConverter}, ConverterParameter=sum}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

            <Grid.Background>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource items}" Converter="{StaticResource newConverter}" ConverterParameter="background" />
            </Grid.Background>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox Name="PersonListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxTemplate}" DataContext="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedItems" Source="{Binding}">
                    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="@name"/>
                    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                </CollectionViewSource>
            </ListBox.Resources>

            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource SortedItems}"/>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
        </ListBox>
```

and here is the code for the converter (everything works, the part for background does return the correct values, but the Background's color just doesn't get set (returning a simple string is enough for Background)):

```cs
class newConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CollectionView items = value as CollectionView;
        if (items == null)
            return null;
        float sum = 0;
        foreach (XmlNode node in items)
        {
            sum += float.Parse(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").InnerText);
        }

        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "sum":
                return sum.ToString("C");

            case "items":
                return items.Groups.Count + " Items";

            case "date":
                DateTime minDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                foreach (XmlNode node in items)
                {
                    if (DateTime.Parse(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("date").InnerText) >= minDate)
                        minDate = DateTime.Parse(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("date").InnerText);
                }
                if (items.Count == 0)
                    return DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                else
                    return "noDateSet";

            case "background":
                if(sum > 0)
                    return "LightGreen";
                if (sum < 0)
                    return "IndianRed";
                else
                    return "SkyBlue";

            default:
                return "missing parameter";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am very thankful for any help, i am sitting at this thing for days now oO :)

Regards

Comment: That is a pretty horrible way of doing things

Comment: show me the right way please :)

Comment: The easies thing would be to ditch the XML and deserialize it to proper CLR objects that can be worked with, the more complex your operations get the more trouble XML means.